# Count with group by in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, count

**Product Table :**  will display all product - list

```
prodid |  name   | size
1      |  prd1   |  30
2      |  prd2   |  40
3      |  prd3   |  50
4      |  prod4  |  20
```

**Product Details:** - when product list is display , i have text box for each product, where resp. user fill value(500,300..etc) and submit data ..this data is store in product details as below

```
id | prdid | userid | value |
1  |  1    |  2     |  500
2  |  2    |  2     |  200 
3  |  1    |  3     |  230 
4  |  3    |  2     |  300
5  |  1    |  4     |  100
```

**What i want :**

```
Product Count  |  Product Name  | Product Size 
   3           |    prod1       |   30
   1           |    prod2       |   40
   1           |    prod3       |   50
               |    prod4       |   20
```

below is list of table :

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    echo "<table border='1'>
      <tr>
         <th>Product Count</th>
         <th>Product Name</th>
         <th>Product Size</th>
      </tr>";

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . ???? . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['size'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";

from above i need 2 things: 
1 } product count - count is common 
2 } highlight with red/green that count for resp user who's value is higher for that prdid from product details
```

> ex :  in product details :
>
> prdid 1 has 3 count
>
> user for prdid 1  are  3 ( 2,3,4) out of which userid 2 has higher
>   value which is 500 hence only his product column for that prodid will
>   he green else red

hope you guys have understood my requirement....

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry bro , my mind is not working right now ..please dont tell me to read that article :( ...btw i m very bad in reading ....pls help widout reading article

Comment: why minus ...any one tell me ...pls before closing any one provide me answer

Comment: Delete this. Come back when your mind is working.

Comment: hahah..good one ...i tried my best... with group by ...but not able to find any ....it would be great if you would help me ..as i need to submit this task by today itself ...actually i am more in management ...have learn php and mysql via google

Comment: Management? But not time management.

Comment: pls sir ..pls...your master its sec time for you ..pls understand week person ...i tried ..else why i would be here ..waiting for answers

Comment: You're not prepared to read 250 words. Why should I bother?

Comment: sir ..i am not use of http://sqlfiddle.com/ ...again i have to learn its and then have to provide u details ..and btw ....i have given data for resp ..table

Comment: Hi if my answer has cleared your query can you please mark it as accepted. So that it will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Hi since your select columns were not in group by clause I think you might have faced some problems. And you have to do left join so that you can get the product details of **prd4** which is having count **0** else you wont get that record.

The following query works fine :

```
SELECT count(pd.prdid) AS productCount, p.name, p.size 
FROM `product` AS p 
LEFT JOIN product_details AS pd ON p.prodid = pd.prdid
GROUP BY p.name,p.size
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this query :

```
SELECT COUNT(details.*) AS NbProduct, product.name, product.size FROM details JOIN product ON product.id = details.product_id GROUP BY product.name
```

Comment: hi the list will be seen from product table and not from product details table and count will be from product details

Comment: I think the query will match what he ask in the "What I want" table

Comment: my product details will be empty at start ..hence list of product will not be seen ...

Comment: Generally, if an unaggregated column appears in the SELECT, then it also needs to appear in the GROUP BY.